# "Expanding" dimension security (user uploaded attr.)

Tags: security, ssas, cube

I'm new to the world of SSAS and Cubes, and this question/title might be way off (as I have no idea how to formulate it. Apologize if that's the case).

Anyway, here goes. I was asked to take a look on a cube (not made by, making it more complex), allowing user-uploaded *.csv files to limit the data in the Cube.

The setup seems to match the Dynamic Security used here: [Analysis Services Dynamic Security](http://bidn.com/Blogs/analysis-services-dynamic-security)

Three tables are in play

```
+-----------------+
|      User       |
+-----------------+
| (PK) DW_EK_User |
| User            |
+-----------------+

+--------------+
|  UserUpload  |
+--------------+
| DW_EK_Upload |
| DW_EK_User   |
| DW_EK_Person |
| GroupNo      |
| GroupLabel   |
+--------------+

+-------------------+
|      Person       |
+-------------------+
| (PK) DW_EK_Person |
| __                |
| __                |
| __                |
+-------------------+
```

The user now uploads a *.csv with ID's of interest, including a label. These are temporarily stored in the fact-table UserUpload and used to filter and only show the results for included ID's.

My question is, if its possible to include the uploaded GroupLabels as a filter?

If my *.csv look like this:

```
ID1 GroupA
ID5 GroupA
ID2 GroupA
ID2 GroupB
```

I would like to be able to see the measures for the individual groups. Now I see the measure for all ID's.

I'm looking into Named Sets, but the data is in the "wrong" table to do like this:

```
Exists(     
        StrToSet("[User].[User].[All].[" + UCase(Mid(Username, InStr(1, Username, "\") + 1)) + "]"),
[Person].[DW EK Person].[All].Children,
        "Measure")
```

This will return the Username from the User-Dimension.

Comment: If anyone can redirect me to another formulation of my question or in other way let me in the right direction I'll appreciate it ! :)